# HttpSession is null in RESTful web service?

Tags: web-services, jersey, jax-rs, httpsession

In my web services class using(jersey) `@Context` I injected `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, `ServletContext` objects for authentication i called a `ValidateUser` servlet.

```
@Path("/server")
public class WebServer { 
    @Context 
    private ServletContext context; 

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @POST
    @Path("/auth")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) throws IOException, ServletException{ 
    ....
    context.getRequestDispatcher("/ValidateUser")include(request, response);
    ...
    }        
}
```

in ValidateUser.java i created session after validations as:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

Up to now everything is working fine but when I call:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

in Logout Servlet session is `null`.  I know restful web services are stateless but i need to maintain session at server side is there any way i can achieve this?  What about `@PerSession` annotation?  Will it be useful in this scenario?

Comment: which server you are using ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati Tomcat 7 web server

Comment: is this throw any error ? your code is right may be something wrong create problem because of your server configuration.

Comment: Yes Session is null.in web app it will work since i am using in web services its giving problems..

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to debug your sessions:

- Can you see the session cookie being created on your client?
- Are you sure you aren't using multiple frontends?  Maybe you need to persist your sessions to the database?
- Could the session's have timed out?  Could it be a long time between the validate call and the logout?

> What about @PerSession annotation? Will it be useful in this scenario?

The `@PerSession` is going to use the same underlying session information.  I don't think it is going to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for reply, I came to know that its difficult to maintain session in restful web services so i implemented token mechanism.I store token in database instead of creating session and for every request i am checking the token in db, in logout i am deleting token from db.

Comment: Many web frameworks allow you to persist your session in the database which is similar to the mechanism you are using.  Glad it's working for your @PSrinivasgoud.